# Safari envia $_FILE como sendo vazio (NULL) via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, null

tenho um script que faz upload de imagem que funciona normalmente com Chrome, EDGE, Firefox e Opera. Mas ele não funciona com Safari. O navegador Safari abre a janela do windows para eu escolher uma imagem. Quando ele deveria fazer upload, ele envia os dados da imagem escolhida como sendo NULL (vazio). Já li vários tópicos e artigos, mas nenhum deles resolveu meu problema.

Alguém pode me ajudar a entender onde está o erro?

No PHP tem o seguinte:

```
    <form id="formImg" style="cursor: pointer;" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post">
      <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload[]" onchange="saveImg()" onClick="" accept='image/*' >
   </form>
```

Já tentei usando na TAG form o seguinte `action:"javascript:;" accept-charset="utf-8";` que eu li em um artigo. Mas nada muda.

O js tem o seguinte:

```
function saveImg()
  {

        $('#formImg').ajaxSubmit({
        url  : 'upload.php',
        type : 'POST',
     // async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      headers: { 'cache-control':'no-cache' },
      success: function (response) {

           if (response === "OK") {
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert (response);
            }
         }  

     });
```

Já usei com e sem os atributos cache, contentType etc. Nada funcionou. Também coloquei na head do html o seguinte:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Li em outros artigos que esse problema do cache poderia interferir. Mas isso também não mudou nada. Nem com, nem sem. Continua sem funcionar no Safari.

Por fim, no php que processa os dados (upload.php), coloquei um pequeno código que me permite sempre saber se ele está enviando os dados como NULL (vazio),

```
    if($_FILES['fileUpload']==NULL){
  echo "Vazio";
  exit;}
```

e em todas as tentativas, ele sempre retorna "Vazio". Já nos demais navegadores, funciona normalmente.

Alguém pode ajudar? Não sei o que mudar neste código para funcionar no Safari. Obrigado!!!

Comment: tenta mudar o teu id para outro nome qualquer e verifica se retorna `null`

Comment: Eu tinha tentado isso tambem, colocado um id diferente, mas continua dando o mesmo erro. Funciona com todos navegadores, menos com Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. Caso alguém também esteja com este problema, segue abaixo a solução que encontrei.

Mudei o js para o seguinte:

```
function saveImg() {

        var myForm = document.getElementById('formImg');
        formData = new FormData(myForm);

    $.ajax({
        url  : 'upload.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response === "OK") {
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert (response);
            }
        }  

    });
};
```

Com isso, o envio funcionou em todos os navegadores (incluindo Safari) dentro do windows.